# Why aren't zsh start files sourced by Linux desktop login shell?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am using `Cinammon`  desktop and would like to have certain commands available in `Run dialog` which just executes commands. I am appending `~/bin` to `PATH` in `.zshenv` but this works only for interactive shells. I have tried it with `.zlogin`/`.zprofile` but to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1):

*ZSH* startup files are not read by *Cinnamon* or your DM (display manager) because, well, they are *ZSH* startup files and not *Cinnamon* startup files.

Where you have to make these settings in order for them to be available in your Cinnamon session mainly depends on how you start it and which distribution you are using. Unfortunately there seems to be no *100%-sure-to-work-everywhere* way to make this configuration. But one of the following files might work:

- `~/.profile`. This is also read by `bash` and some other shells on startup, but **not** by *ZSH*
- `~/.xprofile`
- `~/.xsessionrc`
- possibly `.xinitrc`, although it is usually used to start X11 user sessions directly without the help of an display manager.

I would suggest to remove the settings form your *ZSH* configuration, so that you can easily check if and how the settings are made without interference. Furthermore, once it works, it should no longer be necessary to configure `PATH` in *ZSH* as it will be inherited from the desktop sesssion.